# concatenating file names in a variable

Tags: shell-script, ksh, variable

I am attempting concatenate file names to use in a ftp mdelete command.  Each file name needs to be separated by a space in order for the mdelete command to work.  The $i variable is in a loop and I am attempting to assign the file name located into $i to $FILESTODELETE in addtion to the file names already in $FILESTODELETE

```
  for i in `ls`
    do    
    $FILESTODELETE = "$FILESTODELETE $i "
        .....
     END
......     

mdelete $FILESTODELETE
```

Comment: realy `$FILESTODELETE = "$FILESTODELETE $i "` with spaces arround = ? you should delete them: `$FILESTODELETE="$FILESTODELETE $i "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set -- *
filenames="$*"
```

As long as you haven't modified your environment's value for $IFS, the above is all you need to get all of the names of not-dot files in the current directory into a single string as divided by spaces and sorted by locale in any POSIX shell. If you have modified $IFS, then whatever its first character is will sub for the single space divider just mentioned instead.

Note, though, that the above is no guarantee that said filenames don't also contain spaces, or newlines, or basically any character but NUL or / - those probably aren't in the filenames.

Answer (score 2):

With a new enough ksh version (not sure exactly how new is new enough), you should just be able to do:

```
files_to_delete=( * )
...
mdelete ${files_to_delete[@]}
```

The first line creates `files_to_delete` as an array whose elements are the files in your current directory (returned by the `*` glob), and the second line expands `files_to_delete` as a space-separated (assuming the default value of `$IFS`) string.

Or, with any POSIX compatible shell at all, you could avoid the variable entirely, and just go directly with:

```
mdelete $(echo *)
```